# How do I select null if no rows match in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, row

I have the following query:

```
SELECT c.customer_id
FROM order o
JOIN customer c USING (customer_id)
WHERE c.time >= '2021-01-01 10:00:00' AND c.time < '2021-01-01 11:00:00'
    AND (0 IN (22) OR o.product_id IN (22))
LIMIT 1
```

As long as there is at least one match, one row will be returned, however if there is no match, then there will not be any rows.

Is it possible to return one row with null value if there is no match?

Comment: Hint: `Left Join` [Left join](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-left-join)

Comment: @Georgy I've tried, it does not return null, it returns an empty row..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution is a `LEFT JOIN`, but starting with the customers table.  However, it is a little complicated:

```
SELECT o.customer_id
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN
     order o
     ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id AND
        o.time >= '2021-01-01 10:00:00' AND
        o.time < '2021-01-01 11:00:00'
LIMIT 1;
```

Note that this is returning `customer_id` from the *orders* table.  That is how it is `NULL` if there is no match.

The above does assume that you have at least one customer, which seems like a reasonable assumption.

An alternative is `UNION ALL`:

```
WITH c as (
      SELECT customer_id
      FROM customer c JOIN
           order o
           USING (customer_id) 
      WHERE o.time >= '2021-01-01 10:00:00' AND
            o.time < '2021-01-01 11:00:00'
      LIMIT 1
     )
SELECT c.customer_id
FROM c
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM c);
```

And a third alternative might be even simpler, a subquery:

```
select (select o.customer_id
        from order o
        where o.time >= '2021-01-01 10:00:00' AND
              o.time < '2021-01-01 11:00:00'
        limit 1
       ) as customer_id;
```

If the subquery returns no rows, then the result is `NULL`.

Comment: @Ben empty can be technically considered as null
Check `column is null`, It will return true

Comment: @Ben If the query  does not return any rows then it can throw empty dataset exception, but did you check on result with empty rows?

Comment: @Ben . . . The question is:  "Is it possible to return one row with null value if there is no match?"  All of the the queries in this answer do that.  If you have a different question, then perhaps you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to check "left joined" table row

```sql
select 
    case when c.customer_id is null then null else o.customer_id end 
from order as o 
  left join customer_cte as c using (customer_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have to tables `Customers` and `Orders`, and there is a one-to-many relation between Customers and Orders: Every Customer has zero or more Orders, every Order belongs to exactly one Customer, namely the Customer that the foreign key `CustomerId` refers to.

Every Customer has a property Time. (Are you sure Time is a Customer property, not a property of an Order?). You have two DateTime values: timeStart and timeEnd, and from every Customer that has a value for property time between timeStart and timeEnd, you want one of his Orders, doesn't matter which one, or null if this Customer doesn't have any Orders.

In baby steps:

```
DateTime timeStart = ...              // = '2021-01-01 10:00:00'
DateTime timeEnd = ...                // = '2021-01-01 11:00:00'

IQueryable<Order> allOrders = ...
IQueryable<Customer> allCUstomers = ...
IQueryable<Customer> customersWithinTimeRanges = allCustomers
    .Where(customer => timeStart <= customer.Time and customer.Time < timeEnd);
```

In words: from all Customers, keep only those Customers that have a value of property Time that is between timeStart and timeEnd (using propery <= and <)

Now from every Customer within time range, you want one of his Orders, or null if the Customer doesn't have any Order.

> Whenever you have a one-to-many relation, like Schools with their zero or more Students, Cities with their zero or more inhabitants, or in your case: Customers with their zero or more Orders, and from every "one" you want zero or more of his "many" items, consider to use one of the overloads of [Queryable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin?view=net-5.0)

I almost always need the overload with a parameter `resultSelector`

```
var customersWithAnOrder = customersWithinTimeRanges.GroupJoin(
    allOrders,

    customer => customer.Id,        // from every Customer take the primary key
    order => order.CustomerId,      // from every Order take the foreign key

    // parameter resultSelector: from every Customer with his zero or more Orders
    // make one new object:
    (customer, ordersOfThisCustomer) => new
    {
         // select the Customer properties that you plan to use:
         Id = customer.Id,
         Name = customer.Name,
         ...

         Order = ordersOfThisCustomer.Select(order => new
         {
             // select the Order properties that you plan to use
             Id = order.Id,
             Date = order.Date,
             ...

             // not needed, you already got the value in property Id:
             // CustomerId = order.CustomerId
          })
          // you don't need all Orders of this Customer, you only want one,
          // don't care which one or null if this Customer doesn't have any Orders
          .FirstOrDefault(),
    });
```

Sometimes the database doesn't allow you to do `FirstOrDefault` if you haven't sorted the sequence. In that case, sort before FirstOrDefault:

```
Order = ordersOfOfThisCustomer.Select(order => new {...})
        .OrderBy(order => order.Date) // or whatever you want to sort on
        .FirstOrDefault(),
```